# How to know why system can't find dll?

Tags: windows, dll

I've used Dependency Walker program and found that my program misses following dll: `wlanapi.dll` (+ several other dlls).

However this dll is located here:

```
c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-wlansvc_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_fa6a47c21b85ab79\wlanapi.dll
```

So how can I know why the dll can not be found? Can I print "all visible to system dlls" or something like that?

Comment: Just because it exists doesn't mean that's the one that its linked to

Comment: The dll is not in a place where the program knows where to look. Try adding that dll location to your PATH.

Comment: @MaQleod this is the dll from Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package, i expect that installer made all necessary changes in system.

Comment: Is this a domain computer? If so, there may have been policies in place that caused it to not be able to edit the PATH variable or register the dll properly.

Comment: @MaQleod this is regular Windows Server 2008 R2 machine. Workgroup machine. hmm... probably i should try install Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package as administrator...

Comment: i've reinstalled Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package as administrator but this didn't helped.

Comment: i've found that `MSVCR110D.DLL` is totally missing but it must came with Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package. i just don't why this dll was not installed.

Comment: VS2010 uses MSVCR100.DLL. Do a binary search on the program and look for references to wlanapi.dll hopefully it'll also include some information on the version it's looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the dll may not be registered.  Go into the command prompt (Start -> run -> cmd) then go to the path where that file is at by typing the following in the command prompt:

```
cd c:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft-windows-wlansvc_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.17514_none_fa6a47c21b85ab79\
```

once there type

```
regsvr32.exe wlanapi.dll
```

You could copy the dll files into the c:\windows\system32 directory to make it a little easier so you don't have to type as much if you'd like.

Another solution to this may be to copy the dll files that the program is missing into the directory where that program is installed but that doesn't always work.

Comment: such error: "The module "wlanapi.dll" was loaded ut the entry-point DllRegisterServer was not found. Make sure that "wlanapi.dll" is a valid DLL or OCX file and them try again."

Comment: i don't think coping dll is a good idea. Windows supposed to find them itself in `winsxs`. that's what for this folder exist.

Comment: Oh, didn't realize it was a server machine till you posted that a few mins ago up there.  I didn't realize the dll system worked differently on those versions of windows.  I found this, it might help.  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbinterop/thread/d5c5ff4a-63d3-49ea-a20d-50ef45924b2e/  

Someone mentioned "This behavior may occur if you try to register a DLL by using Regsrv32 while you are logged on using an account that does not have administrative credentials."  If this is the problem, maybe simply logging in as administrator might make whatever you're trying to do work.

Comment: hm... i think the root of the problem is that i'm missing much more important `MSVCR110.DLL` and `MSVCP110.DLL`. I've installed "Microsoft Visual C++ 2012 Redistributable Package" (and reinstalled many times) but dll still can not be found. it supposed to be there but i can not find them in C:\Windows. i do not know how to trobleshoot. I probably can copy dll's from another machine...

Comment: You can also search google for "download drivername" and then pop it in the c:\windows\system32 folder and try the app again.  This has worked for me in the past.  You're worrying more about copying dll's then I think you should be.  Unless you're over writing files I wouldn't worry about it.  Moving them is a different matter possibly.

Comment: i just wonder why just installing is not enough. moreover wlanapi.dll ut it just located in the wrong folder. i think it supposed to be in system32 or system32 should contain hard link to it

Comment: It may be that that redistributable is in the visual c++ 2010 package not 2012.  Might try installing that one too, technically you could try 2008 and the other ones too but I'm wondering if since the filename ends with msvcr110.dll it may be for 10 (2010)

Comment: Hm, did a little reading up on that winsxs folder and maybe it is wise to keep the files there (not saying it'd break anything necessarily).  But it's designed to basically allow you to easily have multiple versions of the same file (the files you're missing may be installed from 2010 or 2012 but each version probably has a copy of the same file and it stores them in that directory in their own sub folders probably.  Here's more info on the winsxs folder:
http://www.winvistaclub.com/f16.html

Answer (score 1):

The DLL being within winsxs (the repository of all files possibly available to Windows or dot NET application) but nowhere else means that the underlying feature if not presently installed or more exactly enabled on that particular Windows 7 or 2008R2 machine. This can be solved by enabling it through the dedicated "Windows feature enabling or disabling" control panel.

Searching `Microsoft-Windows-Wlansvc` through Google pointed me to [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766511%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) and a lot more information about this "component" or feature.